# Combining the output of a function that runs multiple times into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, function

Essentially my goal is to save the output of my def function into a list that I can then save into a data frame. I was working with the function and realized that every time I changed the definition function, it would make the changes to one output at a time. Then I realize that for each output the function is calling itself over and over again. I think I have to call a variable outside of this function that can combine all the calls that the function outputs but I'm not sure how.
*Updated code with suggestion*

```
def getEmails():
    
        creds = None
      
    
        if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
      
     
            with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
     
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
      
      
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
      
     
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
      
      
        result = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
        messages = result.get('messages')
      
    
        for msg in messages:
            txt = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg['id']).execute()
            m_id = msg['id'] # get id of individual message
         
            try:
              
                payload = txt['payload']
                headers = payload['headers']
      
            
                for d in headers:
                    if d['name'] == 'Subject':
                        subject = d['value']
                    if d['name'] == 'From':
                        sender = d['value']
                    if d['name'] == 'Date':
                        date = d['value']    
                        
                parts = payload.get('parts')[0]
                data = parts['body']['data']
                data = data.replace("-","+").replace("_","/")
                decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)
      
                soup = BeautifulSoup(decoded_data , "lxml")
                body = soup.body()
                names = soup.body.findAll('p')
                page = soup.find('p', text=re.compile('has been listed on ')).getText()
                if page:
                    match = re.search(r'has been listed on '+'\\b\w+\\b'+' ', str(page))
                    if match:
                        site = match.group()
                else:
                    None
                    
                def Convert(string):
                    li = list(string.split())
                    return li    
             
                if sender ==  'Cryptocurrency Alerting <alerts@mail.cryptocurrencyalerting.com>':
                    site = site.replace("has been listed on ", "")
                    s = list(Convert((str(site))))
                    results = []
                    results.append(s)
                    print(results)
                   
        
            except:
                pass
      
      
    
    getEmails()
```

The output of this function looks like this

```
[['OKEX']]
[['OKEX']]
[['OKEX']]
[['Kucoin']]
[['Kucoin']]
[['Kucoin']]
[['Kucoin']]
[['Hotbit']]
```

I've tried
`k = print(s, end="", flush = True)`

which outputs
`['Hotbit']['Hotbit']['OKEX']['OKEX']['OKEX']`

However, this doesn't make it a list. I need a variable outside of this function so that it can take the output and put it inside a list.

Comment: Save s in list , return list

Comment: @sahasrara62 how can I do that?

Comment: `results = []` and later `results.append(s)` instead of `print(s)`, then `return results`

Comment: @JanWilamowski that gave this ``[['Hotbit']]
[['Hotbit']]
[['OKEX']]
[['OKEX']]
[['OKEX']]
[['OKEX']]``

Comment: @JanWilamowski maybe a while loop?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, please update your code. Since `s` is already a list, you could also use `results.extend(s)`, depending on what your result should look like.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Here I edited the code with the edited out put it just added brackets to the outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assemble your results and return them from the function:

```py
def getEmails():
    results = []

    # lots of code...

            if sender ==  'Cryptocurrency Alerting <alerts@mail.cryptocurrencyalerting.com>':
                site = site.replace("has been listed on ", "")
                s = list(Convert((str(site))))
                results.append(s)
                   
    return results


# retrieve the results
results = getEmails()
```